# automatically saving attachments outlook convert to csv

Tags: excel, vba, csv, outlook

I have used the following code to automatically save Excel files with certain text in the file name to a specific location as they arrive in my Outlook folder:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"
 For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Then
            If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Test") Then
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
      End If
End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can also have Outlook save the file in .csv format, or at least instruct it to open Excel and perform the task automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Excel to get the job done for you. But you need to save the attached file on the disk anyway. Then in Excel you can open the saved file and save it in the format you need.

See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151?wa=wsignin1.0) to get started quickly.